# Facebook Marketing Graph API stop time filtering

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

With this API call,

```
act_xxx/campaigns?fields=name,start_time,stop_time,effective_status&limit=1000&filtering=[{"field": "effective_status","operator": "IN","value": ["ACTIVE"] }, {"field": "stop_time","operator": "GREATER_THAN","value": "2023-06-06T23:30:00%2B0100"}]
```

I am not able to filter out stop_time that is greater than the specified date. Most of the returned campaigns are stop_time that has already passed, I tried using "2023-06-06" as well but it still returns the same campaigns.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, when doing this filtering we need to specify it using a unix timestamp. So putting `1686058315` instead of 2023-06-06 will work.